# How would I create a Zustand store selector hook wrapper in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, zustand

I am trying to use Zustand as a replacement for React Context to provide a shared state amongst a subset of components, and one of the patterns I find myself using a lot is the shallow, multi-property selector, like so:

```js
// store.ts
interface State {
  data: object,
  setData: (newData: State['data']) => void,
}

const useStore = create<State>(set => ({
  data: {},
  setData: (data) => set({ data }),
});


// Component.tsx
import shallow from 'zustand/shallow';
import useStore from './store.ts';

const { data, setData } = useStore(
  ({ data, setData }) => ({ data, setData }),
  shallow
);

// Use 'data' and 'setData'
```

My understanding is that I need to use the `shallow` equality check when doing this sort of multi-property selector, but this is clearly a very verbose pattern to write out the keys multiple times and always add the `shallow` option, especially if it's more than just one or two keys.

I'd like to create a wrapper hook for `useStore` that will just take a list of keys and handle the rest of this for me, like this:

```js
// store.ts
import pick from 'lodash/pick';

const useStoreState = (keys: (keyof State)[]) =>
  useStore(state => pick(state, keys), shallow)

// Component.tsx
import { useStoreState } from './store';

// Ideally the return value here has the same type as the example above
const { data, setData } = useStoreState(['data', 'setData']);
```

This functions just fine (at least I think it does - I don't know for sure if the `pick` breaks the selector subscription stuff), but I can't for the life of me get the typing to work out correctly.

Zustand's types are pretty complicated and do a lot of inference, but does someone know a way to accomplish this? Am I missing another approach to address this issue?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I would propose the following implementation (which have a slightly different syntax than yours, but it is also less verbose):

```
// Utility function, to allow us to pick fields from the store
const useMulti = <T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
  useStoreFn: UseBoundStore<StoreApi<T>>,
  ...items: K[]
): Pick<T, K> => {
  return items.reduce(
    (carry, item) => ({
      ...carry,
      // No need to use useShallow here, as we fetch the objects one by one
      [item]: useStoreFn((state) => state[item]),
    }),
    {}
  ) as Pick<T, K>;
}
```

Then, the wrapper:

```
// Wrapper store hook
const useStoreState = (...items: Array<keyof State>) =>
  useMulti(useStore, ...items)
```

So in the end, you can access your store with the following:

```
const {data,setData} = useStoreState("data","setData")
```

You can check this [live example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/contexts-x8w2jj?file=%2FREADME.txt%3A36%2C208) that I did if you want to play around